# ASP.NET Core FileStream versus FileResult produce different results

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pdf-generation

I'm generating a PDF file using PDFFlow, on their examples they mostly focus on saving directly to a file by providing a name, but they also support writing to a stream.

Whenever I let PDFFlow write the generated PDF file to a MemoryStream and return said stream using a FileResult from my controller it comes back as invalid (content of the file is `[object Object]`).

If I return `stream.ToArray()` I do get a PDF file but it's completely empty.

Only if I let the application write to a FileStream does the file come out correctly, do I need to do anything specific to get the MemoryStream to work as I do not want to have to generate temporary files.

Using MemoryStream:

```cs
        using var stream = new MemoryStream();

        var documentBuilder = DocumentBuilder.New();
        var mainSection = documentBuilder.AddSection();

        mainSection.AddParagraph("Hello");
        documentBuilder.Build(stream);

        await stream.FlushAsync(cancellationToken);

        return File(stream, "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
```

> Results in invalid file with content `[object Object]`

Using FileStream

```cs
        using var stream = new FileStream("Result.pdf", FileMode.Create);

        var documentBuilder = DocumentBuilder.New();
        var mainSection = documentBuilder.AddSection();

        mainSection.AddParagraph("Hello");
        documentBuilder.Build(stream);

        await stream.FlushAsync(cancellationToken);

        return File(stream, "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
```

> Results in valid file generated inside the project (file returned from the download is still invalid)

Comment: You need to do `stream.Position = 0;`

Comment: Unfortunately that one does not seem to help in this case, if I put that right before the `return File` it has no effect on the outcome. The position however does get set to 0, I verified that with the debugger.

Comment: Just tested in Postman instead of my frontend, I got an error "Cannot access a closed stream". I've had to remove the using statement to let the `FileResult` close the stream itself.
Unsure why the frontend still thought it was getting a file

Comment: Verified it through my frontend aswell after a small change with how Axios fetches the blob and it's working, can you provide a full answer @Charlieface so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: And remove the `using`, as you are passing it straight through